# Parsing JSON Github API - Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, github-api

I have this in my `views.py`:

```
def profile(request):
    parsedData = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('user')
        req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/repos') 
        jsonList = []
        jsonList.append(req.json())
        userData = {}
        data = ['owner']
        for data in jsonList:
            userData['html_url'] = data['owner'][0]['html_url']
            userData['created_at'] = data['created_at']
            userData['updated_at'] = data['updated_at']
            userData['forks_count'] = data['forks_count']
        parsedData.append(userData)
    return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': parsedData})
```

This throws me:

```
TypeError at /app/profile/

list indices must be integers, not str
```

This is an example JSON returned by `/repos` on Github:

```
  {
    "id": 77549474,
    "name": "acp",
    "full_name": "kkoci/acp",
    "owner": {
      "login": "kkoci",
      "id": 3047897,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/3047897?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/kkoci",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kkoci/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/kkoci/acp",
    "description": null,
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/kkoci/acp/deployments",
    "created_at": "2016-12-28T17:23:45Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-28T17:23:46Z",
    "pushed_at": "2016-12-28T13:00:52Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/kkoci/acp.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:kkoci/acp.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/kkoci/acp.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/kkoci/acp",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 113,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Python",
    "has_issues": false,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "archived": false,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "license": null,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "8.0"
  },
```

I've tried in many ways but the error persists, any ideas?

**EDIT**

The error comes at this line `userData['html_url'] = data['owner'][0]['html_url']` but also on the rest of them, it's just an example of two ways I've been trying this. The error persists.

Comment: I believe the response from github is already a list, so you are adding a list element to your jsonList

Comment: @style, thank you for sharing that the GitHub API response is already a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from github is already a list, so the first element in your `jsonList` is a list and this is the reason for the exception.

Change to:

```
jsonList=req.json()
```

and it should work

Comment: Thank You so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're appending the response to a list.
Then the response only contain one JSON object.

Thus, you don't even have to loop it. Just assign the values directly.

```
data = req.json()
userData = {}
# Copy values right away
userData['html_url']    = data['owner'][0]['html_url']
userData['created_at']  = data['created_at']
userData['updated_at']  = data['updated_at']
userData['forks_count'] = data['forks_count']
```

Then in your response, if the client is NOT expecting a list, no need to append the `userData` to a list type. Just pass it directly as:

```
return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': userData})
```

Answer (score -1):

`data = ['owner']` means `data` is a list contains one string `owner` but not means it is a dictionary contains one key `owner`(correct one should be something like `data={"owner": None}`).

So when you access it like `data["owner"]`, you are trying to use it like a dictionary, but it is a list.

And that's why you get error: `list indices must be integers, not str`.

Comment: That line is actually meaningless since data is set in a for loop

Comment: @style Sure, but as OP was making such basic mistake, I think he should learn something fundamental first, or he won't be able to complete what he want.