# Filter JSON results - Django 1.8 - Github API v3

Tags: python, django, github-api

I'm trying to filter the result of an API query on template, I have this method:

```
def profile(request):
parsedData = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('user')
    req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/repos') 
    jsonList = []
    jsonList=req.json()
    for data in jsonList:
        userData = {}
        userData['html_url'] = data['html_url']
        userData['created_at'] = data['created_at']
        userData['updated_at'] = data['updated_at']
        userData['forks_count'] = data['forks_count']
        repo_instance = Repo.objects.create(name=data['html_url'],created_at=data['created_at'],updated_at=data['updated_at'],forks_count=data['forks_count'])
        repos = Repo.objects.filter(updated_at__lt = timezone.now()).order_by('updated_at')
        parsedData.append(userData)
return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': parsedData})
```

This method, makes a query into an address like this one for example [githubtraining](https://api.github.com/users/githubtraining/repos)

Also stores every repository found into the db.

Now, what I want, is to filter the results obtained from this query into the view of my app, this is what I have on my template:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header"> Url <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
        <th class="header"> Created at <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
        <th class="header"> Updated at <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
        <th class="header"> Forks count <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  {% for key in data %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ key.html_url }}</td>
          <td>{{ key.created_at }}</td>
          <td>{{ key.updated_at }}</td>
          <td>{{ key.forks_count }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}

  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

As You can see, the API returns the repo with some JSON data, one of these items is `updated_at`. What I need is to filter the resulting query by these dates, from newest to oldest update (commit).

I've tried storing them into db, then filter the result, but it's not working this way, also, I think it's not an optimum solution, so, I'll need to "capture" the result before it is shown, and then filter it into my view (html).

Any ideas?

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164181/parsing-json-github-api-django-1-8) for the API response

Comment: Do you want to FILTER or ORDER by the Updated_at? It's not clear

Comment: Well, sorry, I think ORDER would be more appropriate, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a order by on your queryset like this (using the -):

```
repos = Repo.objects.filter(updated_at__lt = timezone.now()).order_by('-updated_at')
```

Comment: Same result, I think this isn't the way to go, because the shown data is coming from a server, not my db

Comment: Maybe I should not show the direct result from the server query, but my db result instead, but that's way too confusing, for such a simple task, isn't there a way to order the data received by the server? Before is saved on db?

Comment: Save the data to the db, then query it ordering as you wish. That shouldn’t be a problem at all